# Drools: Compare 2 Arraylists from the same Object

Tags: java, arraylist, compare, drools

I have a Class and this Class constructs 7 ArrayLists:

```
public class Fruchtplanungsmodul {

    private ArrayList<Crops> fruchtliste1F;
    private ArrayList<Crops> fruchtliste2F;
    private ArrayList<Crops> fruchtliste3F;
    private ArrayList<Crops> fruchtliste4F;
    private ArrayList<Crops> fruchtliste5F;
    private ArrayList<Crops> fruchtliste6F;
    private ArrayList<Crops> fruchtliste7F;

    // Constructor
    public Fruchtplanungsmodul() {
        fruchtliste1F = new ArrayList<>();
        fruchtliste2F = new ArrayList<>();
        fruchtliste3F = new ArrayList<>();
        fruchtliste4F = new ArrayList<>();
        fruchtliste5F = new ArrayList<>();
        fruchtliste6F = new ArrayList<>();
        fruchtliste7F = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    functions for deleting Objects....
}
```

And I want to load Objects in this list with Drools-rules.
I do load the same Objecttyps into all Arraylists. For example, in this rule, I load 4 Objects Crops into the first ArrayList.

```
rule "Körnerlegmunosen: Planung erste Feldrigkeit"
    when
        //$grund:         Grundbedingung(grundbedingung == 1)
        $feld:          Feldrigkeit(feldrigkeit1 == "Körnerleguminosen")
        $m:             Fruchtplanungsmodul()

    then

        Crops erbse = new Crops("Erbse", "Koernerleguminose","BF", "Hafer", "Silomais", "Sommerung", 6);
        Crops ackerbohne = new Crops("Ackerbohne" , "Koernerleguminose", "BF", "Silomais", "Wintergerste", "Sommerung", 4);
        Crops lupine = new Crops("Lupine", "Koernerleguminose", "BF", "Späte Kartoffel", "Winterroggen", "Sommerung", 4);
        Crops sojabohne = new Crops("Sojabohne", "Koernerleguminose", "BF", "Futterrübe", "winterroggen", "Sommerung", 3);

        insert(erbse);
        insert(ackerbohne);
        insert(lupine);
        insert(sojabohne);
        $m.addFrucht1(erbse);
        $m.addFrucht1(ackerbohne);
        $m.addFrucht1(lupine);
        $m.addFrucht1(sojabohne);
end
```

In other rules, I load different Crops into other ArrayLists from the Class Fruchtplanungsmodul().

My Question is: Is there any way to compare Objects from different ArrayLists?

For example, ArrayList "fruchtliste2F" has 4 objects from the type Crops and the ArrayList "fruchtliste3F" also has 4 objects from the type Crops. Now I need to check with a rule if there is one Object with the same Name in both ArrayLists. If this is true, the rule should delete the object from the second list.

Thanks for your help!
Philipp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the arrays you want to check are fixed (i.e. you always want to check array #2 with array #3), then you can do something like this:

```
rule "Delete duplicated"
when 
  $f: Fruchtplanungsmodul()
  $c1: Crop() from $f.fruchtliste2F
  $c2: Crop(name == $c1.name) from $f.fruchtliste3F
then
  //If you want to remove the fact you have inserted too:
  delete($c2);

  //Remove the object from the array
  $f.deleteFrucht3($c2);
end
```

If you want to check all the arrays, then you either create copies of the rule above, or create a way your java class to access the arrays by an index and create a generic rule to compare them all.

Hope it helps,